# Best way to use large IP blacklist to deny access to a Windows 2008 web server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, security, denial-of-service

Basically, I'm looking for a solution similar to the ones mentioned in a similar (but Linux-focussed thread) located [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/15931/best-way-to-use-large-ip-blacklist-to-deny-access-to-a-web-server) so that I can deny access to blacklisted IPs.  I am specifically focussed on trashy form submissions to a number of publicly available websites that I host whose clients don't want CAPTCHAs.  Almost every IP I've traced a bad submission to is on the various blacklists I've checked, so I anticipate knocking out the vast majority of my problems simply by denying these IPs.

I've come across 2 tools ([Peerblock](http://www.peerblock.com/releases/public-releases/peerblock-1.0.0-r181) and [PeerGuardian](http://phoenixlabs.org/pg2/)), but neither of their install pages mention Windows Server 2008 64-bit machines specifically.

There is an installer for Vista/Windows 7 64-bit machines mentioned on the Peerblock downloads page, but that is a little disconcerting for me for 2 reasons: 1) I would feel better if it mentioned Windows Server 2008 explicitly and 2) this leads me to believe that the software's intended use is for personal machines and I need a server-grade solution.

Anybody got software-based alternatives to recommend ... or have experience with these running on 2008 64-bit boxes?

Note: I realize that a hardware firewall is a better solution, but I have an immediate need and a cost crunch on my hands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Commenting instead of answering because your question is specific.  I suggest you look at the Astaro Security Gateway. There is a free basic version that should let you do what you want .. all you need is an old PC with 2 NICS.

Comment: Note: same user asked about another way to solve the same problem in another question.  No problem, but noting for the record.  http://serverfault.com/questions/86747/how-do-i-block-specific-ips-and-ip-ranges-in-iis7

Comment: Just to clarify, this question is about where to find an external program capable of handling blacklists with 1000s of IPs and the other is about how to enable the "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions" in IIS7 on W2K8 to deny specific IPs.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any apps that run on Vista 64 bit that won't run on Server 2008 64 bit (same code base) unless the vendor restricts it to workstations only.  PeerBlock mentions "server variants" in the first paragraph so it's covered.

Basic IP blocking can be done in the Server firewall also but you won't have a dynamic update service.

Comment: ...I wish I could up vote you, but I'm a newbie.  I missed that part about server variants.  In my case, I've got several servers and a couple hundred IPs and IP ranges, so I'm definitely hoping for more that just the IP blocking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I would feel better if it mentioned
>   Windows Server 2008 explicitly and

Seems to me that it will either install, or fail to install -- I don't see too many likely scenarios in which you'll be hurting anything to give it a try. I've used PB for some testing before and it was a smooth process (of course YMMV).

> 2) this leads me to believe that the
>   software's intended use is for
>   personal machines and I need a
>   server-grade solution.

If you want a dynamically updating list from the likes of PB or PG, I don't see what kind of server-grade solution there would be. The lists either block the IPs or they don't -- were there other server-specific features you were looking for? Especially when you mentioned that you have a budget crunch and need something NOW.

My advice would be to install PB based on your desire for an immediate need and lack of firewall solution.

Comment: Well - the problem with PeerBlock is that it wants to run in the system tray at user logon - which is obviously not a good solution for a server.  I could set it to run at startup but I'm afraid that I couldn't predict its behavior.

As far as I can tell - there is no way to prevent it from launching an update window when it launches ... even if all updating is off.  Is there a system tray when there are no users?